# Delete specific item from local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webkit, local-storage

I have a note taking application that im working on . Its made to look like Google Keep

It saves each note in local storage .

I would like to add a delete option to each of the notes (similar to Keep) , but don't know know to do it.

The full code is on my Github page https://github.com/oxhey/keep

HTML :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Notes</title>
    <link href="styles/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="window.css">
</head>
<script>

        var nw = require('nw.gui');
        var win = nw.Window.get();
        win.isMaximized = false;
    </script>

<body id="gui">
    <header class="app-header">
      <ul style="margin-top:0.3px">
    <li><a href='#' title='Close' id='windowControlClose'></a></li>
    <li><a href='#' title='Maximize' id='windowControlMaximize'></a></li>
    <li><a href='#' title='Minimize' id='windowControlMinimize'></a></li>
  </ul>

  <h2 style="margin-top: 10px;margin-left: 20px;color: #fff;">Notes</h2>

    </header>

    <section class="main-section">
        <article class="note add-note">
                <h1 class="note-title"></h1>
                <p class="note-content">Add a note</p>
        </article>
    </section>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

<script>


        // Min
        document.getElementById('windowControlMinimize').onclick = function()
        {
            win.minimize();
        };

        // Close
        document.getElementById('windowControlClose').onclick = function()
        {
            win.close();
            gui.App.closeAllWindows();
        };

        // Max
        document.getElementById('windowControlMaximize').onclick = function()
        {
            if (win.isMaximized)
                win.unmaximize();
            else
                win.maximize();
        };

        win.on('maximize', function(){
            win.isMaximized = true;
        });

        win.on('unmaximize', function(){
            win.isMaximized = false;
        });


    </script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Javascript : Main.js

```
    var Strings = {
    'en-us': {
        DEFAULT_TITLE: "Title",
        ADD_NOTE: "Add a note",
        SEARCH_PLACEHOLDER: "Search Jin's Keep"
    }
};

var Lang = Strings['en-us'];

var Keys = {
    ENTER: 10
}

var notes;



function Note(title, content, id) {
    Note.numInstances = (Note.numInstances || 0) + 1;
    this.id = id ? id : Note.numInstances
    this.title = title;
    this.content = content;
}

Note.prototype.render = function(index) {
        var elem = $('<article class="note" data-index="' + index + '"><h1 class="note-title">' + this.title + '</h1><p class="note-content">' + this.content + '</p></article>');
        $(".add-note").after(elem);
}

Note.prototype.toJSON = function() { 
    return {
        id: this.id,
        title: this.title,
        content: this.content
    };
}

function createNote() {
    var elem = $(".add-note");
    var title = elem.find(".note-title");
    var content = elem.find(".note-content");

    elem.removeClass("active");
    title.hide();

    if(title.text() != Lang.DEFAULT_TITLE || content.text() != Lang.ADD_NOTE) {
        var id = notes ? notes.length+1 : 1;
        var note = new Note(title.text(), content.text(), id);
        notes.push(note);
        note.render(notes.length-1);

        title.text(Lang.DEFAULT_TITLE);
        content.text(Lang.ADD_NOTE);
        saveNotes();
    }
}


function activateNote(note) {
    var title = note.find(".note-title");
    note.addClass("active");
    title.show();
    if(isEmpty(title.text())) {
        title.text(Lang.DEFAULT_TITLE);
    }
}

function saveCurrentNote() {
    var noteElement = $(".note.active");
    if(noteElement) {
        console.log("will save this element: ", noteElement[0]);
        var noteIndex = noteElement.attr("data-index");

        var note = notes[noteIndex];
        note.title = noteElement.find(".note-title").text();
        note.content = noteElement.find(".note-content").text();

        saveNotes();

        deactivateCurrentNote(noteElement);
    }
}

function deactivateCurrentNote(note) {
    note.removeClass("active");
    var title = note.find(".note-title");
    if(isEmpty(title.text()) || title.text() == Lang.DEFAULT_TITLE) {
        title.hide();
    }

    $(":focus").blur();
}

function isEmpty(string) {
    return string.replace(/\s|&nbsp;/g, '').length == 0;
}

function addTabIndex() {
    tabIndex = 3;
    $(".note .note-content, .note .note-title").each(function() {
        var el = $(this);
        el.attr("tabindex", tabIndex++);
    });
}


function loadNotes() {
    var rawObjects = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("notes"));
    if(rawObjects && rawObjects.length) {
        rawObjects.forEach(function(obj, index) {
            obj.__proto__ = Note.prototype;
            obj.render(index);
        });
        return rawObjects;  
    } else {
        console.warn("Couldn't load any note because local storage is empty.");
        return [];
    }
}

function saveNotes() {
    localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notes))
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    notes = loadNotes();
    addTabIndex();

    $(".note").each(function() {
        var note = $(this);
        var title = note.find(".note-title");
        if(isEmpty(title.text()) || title.text() == Lang.DEFAULT_TITLE  ) {
            title.hide();
        }
    });

    $(".main-section").on("click", ".note .note-content, .note .note-title", function(evt) {
        var note = $(this).parent();
        activateNote(note);
        //console.log('2 - Setting content editable to true', evt);
        var noteSection = $(this);
        noteSection.prop("contentEditable", true);
    });

    $(".main-section").on("click", ".note .note-title", function(evt) {
        //console.log("3 - Clearing TITLE's text");
        var title = $(this);
        if(title.text() == Lang.DEFAULT_TITLE) {
            title.text("");
        }
    });

    $(".main-section").on("click", ".note .note-content", function(evt) {
        //console.log('4 - Clearing CONTENT text', evt);
        var content = $(this);
        if(content.text() == Lang.ADD_NOTE) {
            content.text("");
            content.focus();
        }
    });

    $(".main-section").on("click", function(evt) {
        if(evt.target == this) {
            //console.log('5', evt);
            var currentNote = $(".note.active");
            if(currentNote.length) {
                //console.log('5.a');
                if(currentNote.hasClass("add-note")) {
                    console.log('5 - Creating a new note');
                    createNote();
                } else {
                    console.log('5 - Saving current note');
                    saveCurrentNote();  
                }

                if(currentNote.find(".note-title").text() == Lang.DEFAULT_TITLE) {
                    currentNote.find(".note-title").hide();
                }
            }
        } 
    });

    $(".main-section").on("keypress", ".note .note-content, .note .note-title", function(evt) {
        var currentNote = $(".note.active");
        console.log('6');
        if(evt.which == Keys.ENTER && evt.ctrlKey) {
            console.log('2');
            if(currentNote.hasClass("add-note")) {
                createNote();
            } else {
                saveCurrentNote();  
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: @Satpal Its in multiple files , Github is easier

Comment: @Tom very few people will actually take time out of their day to search through your repo

Comment: @DavidJones Its not that much code . I will put as much of it here as i can.

Comment: @Satpal I have put the code here

Comment: `localStorage.removeItem(key);`

Comment: Do you want to delete a localstorage element that would be: localStorage.removeItem(key), or do you want to delete an element out of the JSON string you stored inside the localstorage?

Comment: @axel.michel I think the second one . I also want it to note to be hidden one its deleted. (I know it goes after refresh cause not in storage)

Comment: @axel.michel I think this would work localStorage.removeItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notes)) , but where would the delete button go

Comment: @Satpal Any ideas on hot to get the delete button working . I have the js code.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Use a data attribute on a delete button and pass that as a parameter to a `removeNote` function.

**HTML**

```
<button class="delete" data-id="1">Delete note</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function () {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  removeNote(id);
});

function removeNote(id) {
  localStorage.removeItem(id);
}
```

Comment: Where would I put the button

Comment: In my example it's tied to the note because of the `id` so I'd add it to the note itself. I think you're going to run into problems if do it another way.

Comment: When a note is created , it takes the <article></article> content and copys it . If i put the button there it doesnt copy it.

Comment: @Tom, sorry, I don't have time to read all your code to work out what it's doing. Your question asked "I would like to add a delete option to each of the notes". If this doesn't work or isn't helpful I'll remove my answer.

Comment: When the note is saved this is saving the text . Any ideas on how to do a button note.content = noteElement.find(".note-content").text();